# Ignore the difference between normal and log-normal distributions

Tags: portfolio-optimization, brownian-motion

I am trying to solve the following problem from a Quant exam (abridged):

> You have 1000 USD. You can only invest in two (independent) stocks, A and B, with
>   the annualized expected returns and volatilities given. Interest rates
>   are zero. Find the fully invested portfolio that minimizes the
>   portfolio volatility.

Then theres the hint, apparently to make calculations easier: "**Ignore also the differences between normal and log-normal distributions**."

My question is about the hint, I am not sure if I interpret it correctly: I would use the fact that for an infinitesimal time step $\mathrm d t$ we have for a stock price $$\frac{\mathrm d S}{S} \sim N(\mu\, \mathrm d t, \sigma^2\,\mathrm d t),$$ which follows from the model of a stock price as a geom. Brownian motion. As a consequence, for a sufficiently small time step $\delta t$ this would imply that *approximately* $$S(\delta t) \sim N((1+\mu) S(0)\delta t, \sigma^2S(0)^2\delta t).$$ The way I would interpret the hint is that I should work with this approximation, instead of using that $S(\delta t)$ is actually (but yet almost inperceivably) log-normally distributed.

**Is my interpretation correct?** I am interested if I understand the hint correctly from a stochastic point of view.

Then, with $\mu_A = 0.1, \mu_B = 0.15, \sigma_A = 0.1$ and $\sigma_B = 0.2$, I would obtain the following: If I invest $\lambda_A$ USD into stock A, and $1000-\lambda_A$ into stock B, then the portfolio value $\Pi$ after $\delta t$ would approximately be distributed as
$$\Pi(\delta t) \sim N\big([1.1\lambda_A +1.15(1000-\lambda_A)]\delta t, [0.01\lambda_A^2+0.04(1000-\lambda_A)^2]\delta t).$$
From this, I would directly obtain:

- The expected profit of the portfolio is maximized if the portfolio consists entirely of stock B (i.e. $\lambda_A = 0$).
- The portfolio volatility would be minimized if I invested 800 USD in stock A and 200 USD in stock B (i.e. $\lambda_A = 800$).

I am interested in properly understanding the underlying mathematics, and not so much in applying a formula I don't understand.

Comment: It sounds like they're just asking for standard, Markowitz portfolio optimization? $ \operatorname{minimize}\(\text{over } \mathbf{w}) \; \mathbf{w}' \Sigma \mathbf{w}$ subject to $\sum_i w_i = 1$ and $\mathbf{w}' \operatorname{E}[\mathbf{R}] = \mu$. Since you just have 2 variables and a risk free rate of 0, the solution is going to be especially straightforward.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! Still, the exam is aimed at people who only have little finance understanding, and I believe they are looking for a basic derivation/solution. If my understanding of the hint is correct, I would actually be able to solve the problem by using the distribution of the portfolio after $\delta t$.

Answer (score 1):

#### Super basic Markowitz min variance problem

Portfolio return is $r_p = w_a r_a + w_b r_b$ hence portfolio variance (under assumption of independent assets is $w^2_a \sigma^2_b + w^2_b \sigma^2_b$

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $w_a, w_b$)} & w^2_a \sigma^2_b + w^2_b \sigma^2_b \\
 \mbox{subject to} & w_a + w_b = 1
 \end{array}
\end{equation}
This is a convex optimization problem where Slater's condition is satisfied. The first order conditions are necessary and sufficient conditions for an optimum. Do a bit of algebra on the first order conditions and you get:
$$ w_a  = \frac{\sigma^2_b}{\sigma^2_a + \sigma^2_b} \quad \quad  w_b  = \frac{\sigma^2_a}{\sigma^2_a + \sigma^2_b} $$

Using your values of $\sigma_a = .1$ and $\sigma_b = .2$, then $w_a = .2$ and $w_b = .8$, as you calculated.

Comment: If you are not sure where the first order conditions come from: they come from the Lagrange Multiplier method for optimization with one equality constraint.

Comment: @AlexC Yeah. The [Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) is $\mathcal{L}(w_a, w_b, \lambda) = w_a^2\sigma_a^2 + w_b^2\sigma_b^2 - \lambda(w_a + w_b - 1)$ then $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial w_a} = 2w_a\sigma_a^2 - \lambda$ which equals 0 under the [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) etc.... Then it's just some algebra. As an alternative, you could of course simply substitute $w_b = 1 - w_a$ to make it a high school level optimization problem in a single variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not exactly what I meant: In what sense should I 'ignore the log-normal distribution'? I guess I am trying to understand this problem from a stochastic point of view.

Comment: @DominikS I honestly don't understand what the purpose of the hint is. Maybe with more context I could guess. To solve a minimum variance problem, all you need is the covariance matrix. Let $R$ be a random vector denoting security returns. Portfolio return with weights $\mathbf{w}$ is given by $R_p = \mathbf{w}' \mathbf{R}$. Hence portfolio variance is $\operatorname{Var}(R_p) = \mathbf{w}'  \Sigma \mathbf{w}$ where $\Sigma = \operatorname{Cov}(R) $ is the covariance matrix. What else is there to know besides $\Sigma$?

Comment: By now, I suspect that they refer to the fact that stock prices are often modeled as geom. Brownian motion, and that therefore the prices are log-normally distributed. But for small times this can be approximated by a normal distribution, and this distinction should be ignored for this problem. I suspect that this is what they meant, after all...

Comment: @DominikS That might make sense: basically a minimum variance problem over an infinitesimal time horizon?